# Horizontally shifting rows based on a value in R

Tags: r

My df looks like this:

```
x a b c d e
0 0 0 1 1 1
1 0 0 1 1 1 
2 0 0 1 1 1
```

I would like to horizontally shift each row based on the value in the x column, so that the new df looks like this:

```
a b c
0 0 1
0 1 1
1 1 1
```

Have been able to find examples of horizontal shifts to replace na, but not a shift based on a value like this - so any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the shift horizontally (`MARGIN = 1`) and transpose with `t()`

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(row) row[2:4 + row[["x"]]]))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    0    1
#> [2,]    0    1    1
#> [3,]    1    1    1
```

---

data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 0:2,
  a = 0, b = 0,
  c = 1, d = 1, e = 1
)
```